# IIS - You are not authorized to view this page error message

Tags: windows, iis, security

I am trying to setup IIS to allow anonymous access via the "IUSR_" account.  I've set the password to that account in Computer Management. I've given that account permissions to the physical folder and child folders that the website is being ran on.

Enable anonymous access is checked in IIS for this site, and the Username/password are set correctly.

However, when i go to view the site i get this error:

You are not authorized to view this page
HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

What could be causing this?  I thought maybe the Appplication Pool, but that seems to be setup correctly using the predefined "Network Service" account.

Update:  If i change the anonymous access user to the administrator account, then everything works.  But, ultimately, i cant have the site go live like that.

Update 2: Fixed!  This might not pertain to alot of people here, but it was a Local Security Setting.  I had removed IUSR from "Access this computer from the network" per some security rules a few weeks back.

Comment: "I've set the password to that account in Computer Management"  Why?  Normally, IIS controls the password.  There's no need to do that.

Comment: Yeah, i thought that too.  But before i manually setup the password, it was doing the same thing.

Comment: I reset the password back to the default password by following this: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;297989#top

I guess, the password is stored in multiple places that need to be synced.  However, I am still getting the same error =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reset the password back to the default password by following [this link to Microsoft's KB article](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;297989#top).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Open Administrative Tools
3. Then open Internet Information Services window
4. Further click on the name of local computer (beneath IIS lable) which is on left column
5. Expand the tree and look for your website's folder
6. On right hand column, where your HTML file is listed, right click and choose open.
7. This html file will open in your browser.
8. Then try to open the same page by choosing "browse" option. Most probably, it will show you the error "You are not authorised to view this page."
9. To fix this, right click again on the html file and this time choose All tasks > permission wizard...
10. Just click next, next and finally finish this wizard. It will automatically set the admin permissions and other security settings at ease.
    Hope, this will resolve the issue as it did in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you set up the site right.  Is it possible that you have made a mistake with which site you configured and the address you are attempting to access?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there's only one site configured.  And tested with a different account for the anonymous access, and when I do that it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to IIS manager
2. Select the service which is not working (computername)
3. Right click it and select properties
4. Select directory security
5. Select the Directory Security tab, Click the Edit button of Authentication and access control. A popup will appear
6. Here you can see the username and the password, and change them

Comment: What button is he to press? on line 5

Answer (score -2):

Congrats as you found the cause. Simply share with you a critical KB on the permissions and user rights,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812614